# Iterating the results returned from fetchall_arrayref

Tags: perl, dbi, fetchall

I have a sql wherein I am fetching few records, sorted by full name.

My requirement is to extract chunks of similar names and then do some operation on it.

Say, the sql returns some records containing names like `[name1,name1,name2,name3,name3]`

I need to split them to `[name1,name1] , [name2] , [name3,name3]`

I am able to do it, but I am not happy with my implementation as I have to call `doSomethingWithNames()`twice.

```
while (my $paRecs = $pStatementHandle->fetchall_arrayref({}, 3)){
   foreach my $phRec(@{$paRecs}){
       my $pCurrentName = $phRec->{'FULL_NAME'};
       if ((scalar(@aParentRecords) eq 0) or ($aParentRecords[-1] eq $pCurrentName)){
           push(@aParentRecords, $pCurrentName);
       } else {
           doSomethingWithNames(\@aParentRecords);
           @aParentRecords= ();
           push(@aParentRecords, $pCurrentName);
       }
   }
};
doSomethingWithNames(\@aParentRecords); # This should be inside while loop
```

I believe am running into this issue because while doesn't go into the loop for 
the last iteration as `fetch*` returns `undef`.

Sounds basic PERL stuff, but tried many loop constructs with no luck.
Any pointer will be a great help

Comment: Tip: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.

Comment: Tip: `eq` is for comparing strings. Use `==` to compare numbers.

Comment: Tip: There's no point in putting `a` in front of array names.

Comment: Tip: The final `doSomethingWithNames(\@aParentRecords);` should be `doSomethingWithNames(\@aParentRecords) if @aParentRecords;` (for when there are no records to fetch).

Comment: Tip: Only use `and` and `or` when followed by `return`, `die`, `next`, `last` or some other flow-control operator. Use `&&` and `||` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to postpone existing the loop by converting it into an infinite loop. This requires checking the loop-terminating condition (`!$rows`) twice, though.

```
my $rows = [];
my $prev_name = '';
my @group;
while (1) {
   $rows = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({}, 3) if !@$rows;

   if (!$rows || $rows->[0]->{FULL_NAME} ne $prev_name)
      if (@group) {
         do_something(\@group);
         @group = ();
      }

      last if !$rows;
   }

   $prev_name = $rows->[0]->{FULL_NAME};
   push @group, shift(@$rows);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly @ikegami. Thanks for the solution and for the tips!